# SQLitedatabase crash on get Readable Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio

when I use an activity that uses my database and add the product details to database my app crashes

```
SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
```

And I already implemented the required libraries ...
 my Database Activity

```
public class Database extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "app.db" ;
    private static final int DB_VER = 1 ;
    public  Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VER);
    }
    public List<Order> getCarts() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        String[] sqlSelect = {"ProductName", "ProductId", "Quantity", "Price", "Discount"};
        String sqlTable = "OrderDetail";
        qb.setTables(sqlTable);
        Cursor cursor = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);
        final List<Order> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
          //13:30
            do {
                result.add(new Order(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ProductId")),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ProductName")),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Quantity")),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Price")),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Discount"))
                ));
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());

        }
        return result;

    }
 public void addToCart (Order order){

        SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase(); //here is the crash line
        String query = String.format("INSERT INTO OrderDetail(ProductId,Quantity,ProductName,Price,Discount) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');",
        order.getProductId(),
        order.getProductName(),
        order.getDiscount(),
        order.getPrice(),
        order.getQuantity());

        db.execSQL(query);

    }

    public void cleanCart()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
        String query = String.format("DELETE FROM OrderDetail");
        db.execSQL(query);

    }
}
```

logcat:

```
   Process: com.OverRout.KFood, PID: 2637
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:808)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:793)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:696)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:671)
        at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:264)
        at com.OverRout.KFood.Database.Database.addToCart(Database.java:45)
        at com.OverRout.KFood.food_detail$1.onClick(food_detail.java:47)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat from the crash?

Comment: And do you get a crash with `getCarts()` or `cleanCart()`?

Comment: Without seeing the logcat its a bit of a guess. As you say addToCart crashes, I assume getCarts is called first and this succeeds. I would guess this is because in getCarts the database has been opened, but your not closing the database, so when you try and open the database again in addToCart you're getting an error as the DB is already in use.

Comment: Can you try adding `db.close()` at the end of each function?

Comment: @MichaelDodd  I've added  the logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cause of this error, and the first that you should eliminate, when using SQLiteAssetHelper is that the database that is to be copied from the assets isn't in the expected location.

SQLiteAssetHelper expects that the database file to be copied is in the **databases** folder, within the **assets** folder.

As such it may well be that you haven'y copied the file **app.db** into the **assets/databases** folder/directory.

If it isn't then you would get a log that contains other exceptions in the log e.g. :-

```
2019-01-08 06:13:53.259 1882-1882/? W/SQLiteAssetHelper: copying database from assets...
2019-01-08 06:13:53.261 1882-1882/? E/SQLiteAssetHelper: Couldn't open app.db for writing (will try read-only):
    com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper$SQLiteAssetException: Missing databases/app.db file (or .zip, .gz archive) in assets, or target folder not writable
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.nativeOpenAsset(Native Method)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:744)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:721)
        at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.copyDatabaseFromAssets(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:436)
        at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.createOrOpenDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:400)
        at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:176)
        at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:254)
        at ptfc.populatetablefromcursor.Database.addToCart(Database.java:44)
        at ptfc.populatetablefromcursor.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2894)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2019-01-08 06:13:53.262 1882-1882/? E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 36667 of [0c55d17973]
2019-01-08 06:13:53.262 1882-1882/? E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:36667: (2) open(/data/user/0/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor/databases/app.db) - 
2019-01-08 06:13:53.264 1882-1882/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/user/0/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor/databases/app.db'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14 SQLITE_CANTOPEN): Could not open database
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:211)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:195)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:503)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:204)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:196)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:880)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:865)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:766)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:714)
        at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:264)
        at ptfc.populatetablefromcursor.Database.addToCart(Database.java:44)
        at ptfc.populatetablefromcursor.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2894)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2019-01-08 06:13:53.264 1882-1882/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
```

And then you get the runtime exception :- (basically as per the log you have displayed)

```
    --------- beginning of crash
2019-01-08 06:13:53.268 1882-1882/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ptfc.populatetablefromcursor, PID: 1882
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ptfc.populatetablefromcursor/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14 SQLITE_CANTOPEN): Could not open database
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2914)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14 SQLITE_CANTOPEN): Could not open database
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:211)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:195)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:503)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:204)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:196)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:880)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:865)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:766)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:714)
        at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:264)
        at ptfc.populatetablefromcursor.Database.addToCart(Database.java:44)
        at ptfc.populatetablefromcursor.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2894)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```